# Error to get return of url in spring boot application with javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I'm trying to get the return of the request in the url, with javascript, but I'm having problems.

I have the follow code:

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/linguagens")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Linguagem> linguagens(){
    Map<String, Linguagem> linguagens = new HashMap<>();
    linguagens.put("linguagem", new Linguagem("Java", true));
    return linguagens;
}
```

HTML page:

```
            <button id="verLinguagens">Ver linguagens</button>
        <div id="linguagens">

        </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$('#verLinguagens').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.get("/linguagens")
    .done(function (data) {
        $('#linguagens').html("Linguagens: " + data.linguagem)
        console.log(data.linguagem)
        console.log(data)
    });
```

});

In my page show the result, but show like this:

```
Linguagens: [object Object]
```

how can I show the correct result? like this

```
{
"Linguagem": {
    "nome": "Java",
    "compilada": true
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works!!

```
Linguagens: {"nome":"Java","compilada":true}
```

but, like this, I can put each value of key in some label?
like, value "java" in label with id "javaLabel"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify(data)` to convert the data to a json representation.

Answer (score 0):

Would this give you what you're after?

```js
var data = {
    "Linguagem": {
        "nome": "Java",
        "compilada": true
    }
};

console.dir(data);
var pretty = JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t');
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = pretty;
```

```html
<pre id="content"></pre>
```